# Dynamically style based on angular value passed through

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have an input value that I want to style, based on the value I receive back from the angular variable. So in my cshtml, I have:

```
 <input type="{{d.input_type}}" ng-style={{d.input_type}} == "radio" ? 'width:40px;' : 'width:100px;" @*class="form-control"*@ @*ng-model="Customer.CustStatus"*@ name="question_answer" id="question_answer" required >
```

Then in my angular .js file I have the following:

```
 $scope.Question = {
                Question1: '',
                input_type: ''
            }

            $http.get('/Home/getUserInfo')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.Question = response.data;
        console.log("status:" + response.status);
        console.log("data: " + $scope.Question);

    }).catch(function (response) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', response.status, response.data);
    }).finally(function () {
        console.log("Task Finished.");
    });
```

Based on the value I receive back (which is either "radio" or "text"), I want to have different styling. For example, I want to have a radio button height of 20px and text must be 40px. How would I go about having conditional styling on my input value, based on the text value I receive back from "input_type".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is

```
<input ... ng-style="{'width': d.input_type == 'radio' ? '40px' : '100px'}" ...>
```

So you first specify the property you're going to set and then its value based on your logic.

Comment: Thanks @NikolajDamLarsen, I copied the code from the question and didn't noticed the double brackets :)

Comment: and I wouldn't need to put `d.input_type` between two {}?

Comment: @user1397978 No, Angular already assumes everything passed to the `ng-style` directive is a javascript expression, so it doesn't need to interpolate it using `{{ }}`.

Comment: Nikolaj was faster with the answer but that's the logic :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That works like a charm! Probably an additional but stupid question, with the inline if statement, how would I change it to be "if d.input_type == 'radio' or 'checkbox. can I just say `d.input_type == 'radio' || d.input_type == 'checkbox'`? would it work the same way?

Comment: @user1397978 sure, just wrap the statement inside brackets so you're sure it gets evaluated correctly `(d.input_type == 'radio' || d.input_type == 'checkbox')?...`

Comment: You guys are my heroes and have saved me so much time! Thank you! Upvotes for everyone

Comment: Just a quick advice, also check [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) as you can find examples as well. Sometimes StackOverflow can solve your doubts faster than the official docs but it's always good to have a look at them as well :)